# Ajax-Post data again AFTER success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have got a small application that check metrics for domains that are valuable for SEO. I establish a connection with API and process them to get the relevant data.

Everything works great there and I do get my data, problem is with Javascript main.js that processes that data.

So my main idea is that I have a select input that corresponds to specific API calls, then a textarea where you paste your links. All works great, and I manage to get the response using ajax and build a relevant view corresponding to a specific method selected.

When ajax responds with success, I fetch data, parse it and make relevant function calls. When page is built, on top I need to have a small select box that would make user to select different method and would retrieve data for the same links. After success I have built a  input that correspond to the same select used on main page.

And my question is **How can i send data again?**

So, here is the code

```
$("#parseLink").on("click", function () {
    var textBox = $("#linkInput").val();
    var method = $("#select").val();
    var newTextBox = textBox.split("\n");
    var methodsList = {
        "Social Values": "GetValueSocialSpread",
        "Social Visibility": "SocialGetValueVisibility",
        "Organic Keyword Count": "GetCountDomainKeyword",
        "Seo Visibility": "SeoVisibilityWorld"
    };
    var selectedApi = methodsList[method];
    var dataToSend = {
        url: newTextBox,
        api: selectedApi
    }
    $("#container").replaceWith("<div class='containter text-center'><h1>Loading...</h1><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x'></i></div>");

    function mainFunc() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../parser.php",
            data: {
                data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
            },
            success: function (response) {
                //remove loading
                $("div.text-center").remove();
                $("div.main_holder").append("<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='pull-right'><button id='export' type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Export</button></div></div></div>");

                $("div.main_holder").append("<div class='container'><div class='row'><select class='form-control' id='select'><option>Social Values</option><option>Social Visibility</option><option>Organic Keyword Count</option><option>Seo Visibility</option></select></div></div>");

                var result = JSON.parse(response);
                var jsonObject = result;
                urlArray = [];

                $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                    urlArray.push(k);
                });
                if (method === "Social Values") {
                    socialValues(result, urlArray);
                } else if (method === "Social Visibility") {
                    socialVisibility(result, urlArray);
                } else if (method === "Organic Keyword Count") {
                    organicKeyWordCount(result, urlArray);
                } else if (method === "Seo Visibility") {
                    seoVisibility(result, urlArray);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I tried calling ajax function again, not working... it probably has a simple solution(hopefully)

I am opened to suggestions! And please tell me if you need more elaborate explanation! Was doing it all night :))

Comment: How did you tried calling ajax again?

Comment: jesus, thats my old version sorry!!!! So i call mainFunc() after it is created and add and event listener to select
`$(document).on("change", "#select",function()
  {
   mainFunc();
  });`